# Facebook API endpoint to get campaigns of a certain objective?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to fetch all of my ad campaigns from Facebook whose objective is "WEBSITE_CLICKS" (ie, driving visitors to your site). When I make a GET request against the following:

```
/act_myaccountid/adcampaign_groups?fields=objective,name
```

or, using the official Python Ads SDK:

```
fields = [facebookads.objects.AdCampaign.Field.objective, facebookads.objects.AdCampaign.Field.name]
campaigns = my_user_account.get_ad_campaigns(fields=fields)
```

I get something that looks like:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "objective": "NONE",
  "name": "name1",
  "id": "1234"
},
{
  "objective": "NONE",
  "name": "name2",
  "id": "567"
},
```

I'd like to be able to only get campaigns with that particular objective. Is there a way to do this? I read through the Ads documentation but didn't see anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not documented as far I've seen but the FB Ads Manager UI allows such filtering which also happens to work in external Graph API calls.

Make a call to the API with a filtering parameter like so:

```
filtering=[
  {
    "field":"<FIELD>",
    "operator":"IN",
    "value":[
      "<VALUE>"
    ]
  }
]
```

For example, your request would be:

```
/act_myaccountid/adcampaign_groups?fields=objective,name&filtering=[{"field":"objective","operator":"IN","value":["WEBSITE_CLICKS"]}]
```

Comment: it's not guaranteed to be supported for all requests, but seems to work fine for most.

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement Paul! Any plans for officially supporting a feature like this?

Comment: Works great! In the  PYthonSDK you can easily do something like `my_user_account.get_ad_campaigns(params={'filtering':[{'field':'objective', 'operator':'IN', 'value': ['WEBSITE_CLICKS']}]})`